# ffmpeg could not find codec parameter for stream 2

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm facing "could not find codec parameter for stream 2" when converting mkv file to mp4. I'm using filter_complex to place the watermark at bottom right. But I'm not facing this issue for all mkv files. I've tried -probesize 100 -analyzeduration 10000000. But no change.

Here is my command

[find error_log here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxJWo.png)

[image]

```
ffmpeg -i i.MKV -i logo.png -probesize 100 -analyzeduration 10000000 -filter_complex 'overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w):y=(main_h-overlay_h)' -y 2.mp4  2> videoError2.txt.
```

Comment: `100` is a ridiculously low probesize. Try `-probesize 100M -analyzeduration 100M`

Comment: I've given 100M. But the problem is still there.

Comment: Your ffmpeg is old. Get a new one from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/
Please copy and paste text instead of making images of text.